# Android - Apply background to the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm following the "Styling the Action Bar" tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

And I get a "Cannot resolve symbol" and error on @drawable/actionbar_background

I don't have an "actionbar_background" under drawable, that I understand. What I don't understand is what "actionbar_background" is.

This is part of the code from the example on res/value/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

   <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't have an "actionbar_background" under drawable, that I
>   understand. What I don't understand is what "actionbar_background" is.

it is a resource file, an `xml` or a `png`, stored inside `res/drawable-*`, folders.

Try creating an xml file called `actionbar_background.xml`, and store it iniside `res/drawable` with the following content:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFF00"/>
</shape>
```